# Not able to delete in onDismissible

Tags: dart, flutter, snackbar, dismissible

I have a code, that uses dismissible in the listview (showes items from database). After dismissing an item it is supposed to show snackbar but it is not showing it and it seems that the dismissible is still part of the tree. Can you help me with that?

```
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: count,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);

    return Dismissible(

      key: Key(this.objs[position].id.toString()),
      onDismissed: (direction) {
        setState(() async {
          int result = await helper.delete(this.objs[position].id);
        });
        Scaffold.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text(this.objs[position].title + "dismissed")));
      },
      background: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: const ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.white, size: 36.0)
          )
      ),

      child: ListTile(
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: getColor(this.objs[position].priority),
          child: Text(this.objs[position].id.toString()),
        ),
        title: Text(obj[position].title),
        subtitle: Text(objs[position].date),
        onTap: () {
          debugPrint("Tapped on " + objs[position].id.toString());
          navigateToDetail(this.objs[position]);
        },
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

this is called inside a Scaffold. And objs is a list that contains all my objects from the database.

Here is my delete code that is called inside onDismissed:

```
    Future<int> delete(int id) async {
    Database db = await this.db;
    var result = await db.rawDelete("DELETE FROM $tblT WHERE $colId=$id");
    return result;
  }
```

I've noticed if I delete one item, and immediately try to create another one (I have an option to insert to DB): 
It sometimes throws the error: A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree

**Update**:
Moved the delete part, before setState and I am getting the error: A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree every time I swipe to dismiss

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following code for the `onDismissed:` property.

The problem is the future inside the onDismissed function. We need to reorder the async and await keywords.

Anyway, take care with the timings when removing successive items.

```
onDismissed: (direction) async {
    String title = this.obj[position].title;
    await helper.delete(this.obj[position].id);
    setState(() {});
    Scaffold.of(context)
       .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("$title dismissed")));
},
```

It also moves the async out of the `setState()` and stores the title to be used later by the `SnackBar`.

Comment: thanks. but in this case, there is an error that A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree. @chemamolins

Comment: You could try two things: First get rid of the async behavior and then access the Scaffold through a GlobalKey. I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: You mean I can't use type Future? I use it in other parts of my code too, for asynchronous behaviour

Comment: Yes, you can use futures but I'm not sure if it should be used to delete an item of the list that backs up the ListView. I am afraid the problem you are experiencing has to do with timings. If you access the items directly in `this.obj[position].title` for instance, perhaps you could directly access the list to delete them.

Comment: I used : obj.removeAt(position); (obj is a list here) instead of removing from db. And after this statement I remove it from the db, but I get an error when doing this:
Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4051 pos 14: '_dependents.isEmpty': is not true.
I/flutter (18171): Another exception was thrown: Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.

Comment: I think I have reproduced your problem by using a future. In my case it has been solved by using the snippet above. I have modified the answer.

Comment: For my case, this shows the error that dismissible widget is still part of the tree

Comment: It is important that setState() is called after the await. The error you receive is like calling `setState()` without awaiting and without deleting the item in the list (just try to remove the `helper.delete...` line completely).

Comment: I mean I have already made the changes that you mentioned. deleting before calling setState. But still telling me that A dismissed Dismissible  widget is still part of the tree

Comment: What I mean is that setState() must be called when we are completely sure that the object in the list has been deleted. If setState() is called before actually deleting the object, we get the error.

Comment: Has your code the same order and async and await keywords as above? If so, I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: Yes, same order. but still has the problem that A dismissed dismissible is still part of the tree

Answer (score 0):

Inside content in SnackBar you can try :

```
Text(this.obj[position].title.toString() + "dismissed")
```

Comment: title is a String type